# Combobox AutoCompleteCustomSource C#

Tags: c#, combobox

Display no data in Combobox, Change two Properties
AutoCompleteMode----SuggestAppend and AutoCompleteSource---CustomeSource code what i tried

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Pname FROM product", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
row["Pname"] = -1;
row["Pname"] = "select Product";
ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
AutoCompleteStringCollection mycol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
DataTableReader dr = ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
while(dr.Read())
{ mycol.Add(dr.GetString(0));
}
comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycol;
con.Close();
```

AutoCompleteStringCollection object have all the Items but combobox display nothing

Comment: Why are you doing a simple task in so hard way?

Comment: plz suggest any other way to display items in combobox with autocomplete

Comment: I've updated the answer... Check it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set these properties:

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend; 
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Here is complete code.

```
    AutoCompleteStringCollection mycol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection {
        "Select product"
    };
    using (SqlConnection con = createconnection()) {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("SELECT Pname FROM product")) {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
                while (reader.Read ()) {
                    mycol.Add (Convert.ToString (reader[0]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycol;
```

EDIT:
I think you want to display items in drop down rather than as autocomplete. In that case you need to add to items.

```
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Select product");
    using (SqlConnection con = createconnection()) {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("SELECT Pname FROM product")) {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
                while (reader.Read ()) {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add (Convert.ToString (reader[0]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```